# react native how to draw curve on bottom bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to add a curve in the middle of this bottom bar:

[image: bottom bar image]

This is what I want to do [image]

How can I add a curve on the middle to View?

```
   bottomBar: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          width: '100%',
          height: height * 0.1,
          flexDirection: 'row',
        },
```

Comment: i know this is not an exact solution for you, but you could get some tips if you examine this;
https://codepen.io/butlu/pen/JQMrzd

Comment: just as an option : you can use styled-components. so this way you can use css tricks like :before and :after and implement someting like this. https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics